# uninitialized constant Couch::Couchbase (NameError)

Tags: ruby, couchbase

I have this problem:

```
uninitialized constant Couch::Couchbase (NameError)
      ./features/step_definitions/lib/couchbase.rb:6:in `get'
      ./features/step_definitions/StepsLib.rb:130:in `/^I get couch$/'
      features/test.feature:4:in `Then I get couch
```

The code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'couchbase'

class Couch
  def get
    client = Couchbase.connect(:bucket => "user", :hostname => "192.168.1.50")
    user = client.get("COMMENT-FO-1103")

    return user

    client.disconnect
  end
end
```

I've been loocking all over, and no clue, I'm no ruby expert.

Thanks.

Comment: from what i can understand there is a problem calling Couchbase, i have tryed this code without it beeing a class, and it works perfect, it only happends when i make it a class, and then call it.

Comment: Are you talking about "get" as a instance method when it works and class method when it doesn't? Could you update your example? Because in current state it works perfectly. Have you run this script standalone? It it works for you, probably the environment you gave isn't complete to reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting through IRB and see if you get the same error.

Open up an IRB instance and type:

```
> require 'Couchbase'
```

You'll get a statement back saying:  => true

Then connect as follows:

```
> c = Couchbase.new("http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/MyBucket")
```

This should connect you directly to the bucket you wish to operate on.

Then try:

```
> c.set("mykey", "Some Value")
```

And you should get a confirmation that the object has been set in the Bucket.

Then use:

```
> c.get("mykey")
```

And you should print the value of the object you just set.

Regarding your code above, I'm not sure why exactly you're trying to wrap this call up in a Class?  What is your Use case?

Answer (score 0):

I notice on the [github page](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client) that methods like `get` aren't run on `client` itself, but instead are used in a block argument to `run` like:

`client.run { |conn| conn.get("COMMENT-FO-1103") }`

That's really all I can think of there. Hope it helps.

I do notice that `return user` will prevent the line `client.disconnect` from ever running, as `return` kicks you out of the method entirely.

Comment: yes, Couchbase::Bucket#run yields connection to the block, but it is just self, in the case you shown client will be the same object as conn. I've done this just in case when "client" object didn't captured by the closure